# Display message when roaming in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I want to make an application where I show a message when the user enters a roaming area. Can I do it in blackberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement [RadioStatusListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioStatusListener.html). And in [networkStatusChanged](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioStatusListener.html#networkStateChange%28int%29)
you can check if [RadioInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html) is in [Roaming](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#NETWORK_SERVICE_ROAMING) state